# Error handling login code in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have a phantomjs script where I login to a website and fill out a form. I am testing the login with different credentials and sometimes it doesn't work. I would like to have some error handling code where if the login fails, I can have give alternate instructions. It would look similar to the following code from https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/useragent.js except that I need to know that the login succeeded and the script is through to the next page:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';
page.open('http://www.httpuseragent.org', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var ua = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.getElementById('myagent').innerText;
        });
        console.log(ua);
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```